# Not enough space for letters like j,y in menu

Tags: html, css

I used 000webhost web builder to make my website, and now I want to change some of contents that I wasn't able to change from within the editor.

Most things I planned on worked perfectly fine. The problem I'm having is that menu cuts off the descenders of low hanging letters like "y" and "j". I would like to solve this problem by increasing the size of the menu buttons. Here is snapshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, the CSS file:

```
.vmenu ul
{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:0;
  width:179px;
/* Main Menu Item widths */
  list-style-type:none;
}

.vmenu ul li
{
  position:relative;
}

/* Top level menu links style */
.vmenu ul li a
{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
/*force hasLayout in IE7 */
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*background of menu items (default state)*/
.vmenu ul li a:link,.vmenu ul li a:visited,.vmenu ul li a:active
{
/*background: #414141; color: white;*/
}

/*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
.vmenu ul li a.selected
{
  font-weight:700!important;
/*background: black; color: white;*/
}

/*background of menu items during onmouseover (hover state)*/
.vmenu ul li a:hover
{
/*background: black; color: white;*/
}

/*Sub level menu items */
.vmenu ul li ul
{
  padding:5px!important;
  background:#FFF;
  border:1px solid #D6D6D6;
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
/*Sub Menu Items width */
  top:0;
  font-weight:400;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.vmenu ul li ul li
{
  overflow:visible!important;
}

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .vmenu ul li
{
  float:left;
  height:1%;
}

* html .vmenu ul li a
{
  height:1%;
}

/* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */
.downarrowclass
{
  position:absolute;
  top:12px;
  right:7px;
}

.rightarrowclass
{
  position:absolute;
  top:6px;
  right:5px;
}

/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */
.ddshadow
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  background:silver;
}

.toplevelshadow
{
/*shadow opacity. Doesn't work in IE*/
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: seeing the structure of the HTML would help too.

Comment: Can you put an example page on jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanx for edit RedriderX and sorry for my bad english (im 15 only)

Comment: You have a height of 1% on the anchor. That is what is cutting the letters off. You could try increasing that, or change it to px's or em's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding

```
height:XXpx;
```

or

```
padding-top: XXpx;
padding-bottom: XXpx;
```

to properties of `.vmenu ul li a`?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html it is hard to determine, but I would normally use Firebug to identify the element that is actually doing the cutting off and apply

```
overflow:visible;
```

to that element.  It seems as if the spacing is ok just you want the bottom part of the letters to be visible which are getting hidden by (it seems) a container.

If it is not the case it can be caused by elements below overlapping as they are not positioned properly.  If the list items are floating make sure you clear them properly so they stack up with eachother by adding some kind of clear fix or clear class to you html/css:

```
.clear
{
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:0;
}
```

Then place a div with this class after any floating items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `z-index` with CSS to e.g. `z-index:90;` for li.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `line-height:150%;` to `.vmenu ul li` may help.